# Module 'moduleName' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it

Tags: angularjs

I am new  Angular and I have to implement server-side pagination in my project, so I did everything as it has been done in this example:
[Server Side Pagination In Angularjs Tutorials](https://github.com/rahil471/Server-Side-Pagination-In-AngularJS)

but I get these errors in my web browser console:

```
GET 
http://*********/admin/css/bootstrap.min.css [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 1043ms]

GET 
http://*********/admin/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 1385ms]

GET 
http://*********/admin/css/styles.css [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 1334ms]

GET 
http://*********/admin/lib/angular/angular.js [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 1384ms]

GET 
http://*********/admin/lib/dirPagination.js [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 1383ms]

GET 
http://*********/admin/app/app.js

and

Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module angularTable due to:
[$injector:nomod] Module angularTable is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
```

Please if anyone can help me!

Comment: It looks like your resources aren't making it from the server to the browser properly. Check the the URLs are correct.

Comment: The module angularTable has its sources in dirPagination.js and if it is not retrieved properly this error occurs. If the url for dirPagination.js itself is working, I assume some kind of CORS issue.

Comment: No, this resourses cannot be found, but URLs are ok

Answer (score 7):

this often happens when you do something like ...

```
angular.module('myapp').controller(function() {
});
```

note this code does not create a module called myapp it just references an existing module. The error you are experiencing will happen if you have not yet created the module.

To create the module do this ...

```
angular.module('myapp', []);
```

also, don't forget the ng-app directive in your HTML ...

```
<html ng-app="myapp">
```

of course, this assumes your script files are loading properly. based on your question your files are failing to load and it is therefore no surprise that myapp has not been created. you should check that the files you are trying to load actually exist on your server. also ensure you know which folder is the root folder from which your web server is serving files. This will help you to get the file paths correct.

Comment: I did as you suggest. This is my app.js (just like in the example i mentioned above)

Comment: have you fixed the 404s? this will not work until you are NOT getting 404s

Comment: I can get my index.php page. My folder structure is like here https://github.com/rahil471/Server-Side-Pagination-In-AngularJS and my index.php contains <script src="lib/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="lib/dirPagination.js"></script>
  <script src="app/app.js"></script>

Comment: do you get the HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found ?

Comment: ok you MUST fix that first - make sure the file paths are correct

Comment: My path to index.php is correct and i can get that file. Folders app, lib and css are in the same folder as index.php . File index.php contains <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css"> <script src="lib/angular/angular.js"></script> <script src="lib/dirPagination.js"></script> <script src="app/app.js"></script> , so i dont know why it cannot see those files

Comment: instead of <script src="app/app.js"></script> try <script src="./app/app.js"></script> OR <script src="/app/app.js"></script>

Comment: i tried  <script src="./app/app.js"></script> but still get 404

Comment: try without the . now but leave the slash

Comment: <script src="/app/app.js"></script> doesnt work too :(

Comment: ok i noticed your browser is making request to http://*********/admin/app/app.js - do you know why /admin is in the URL the browser is requesting to?

Comment: In Typicms is defined a route admin/lokali which open my index.php page. So i use //*********/admin/lokali to open index.php page

Comment: ok it looks like Typicms is not giving access to the file system. You need to define a Typicms route which allows file system access - ive not used Typicms before so i cant help much here

Comment: on second thoughts ... if you visit http://yourserver/app/app.js in your browser do you see the app.js javascript file? - if yes then you can always provide a fully qualified URL to your script request - not the ideal solution but it should work ... <script src='http://yourserver/app/app.js'></script>

Comment: i cannot visit myserver/app/app.js, probably i have to define new routes for those files. I will try it and we'll see. Thank you, you give me the idea :)